# How to output even numbers?

Tags: javascript

```
for (count = 1; count < 11; count = count + 2 ) {
     if(count % 2 == 1 ) {
         console.log(count) 
     }
```

This is my code right now and it prints out odd numbers. `1, 3, 5, 7, 9`. I need it to print out `2, 4, 6, 8, 10`. But I can't figure out how. I'm new to javascript

Comment: Look at your `for` loop declaration: `count = 1; count < 11; count = count + 2` What numbers will `count` be?

Comment: For even numbers, you'll need a rest of 0 when dividing by 2. Use `count % 2 == 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start your loop from `2` instead of `1`. There's no need for the modulus test, since you're incrementing by `2`. So the values of `count` will all be either even or odd, depending on the initial value.

```js
for (var count = 2; count < 11; count += 2) {
  console.log(count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

based on your given code, it seems that you are programming the code to find the odd numbers. When you are using the modulus operator to see if it is equal to 1, you are saying that if I take this number, for example, 3, and it does not divide evenly by 2, then it should print that number. What you want is to change the value to 0 at the other end of the double equal sign, that way, when we take the same number, 3, and divide it by 2, we see that it does not divide perfectly, and as a result, it will not print it. Once it moves on to 4, the number will divide evenly, and it will print that number. Therefore to print the even values, you simply need to change the 1 to a 0. Another issue with the code seems to be that you are starting at 1, and incrementing by 2 each time, this will never be able to test even numbers, as it goes 1, then 3 then 5, etc. So in order to check for even numbers, either change the starting value to 0, or increment by 1 instead.